# Mod rewrite reverting to original url after load

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a .htaccess file to rewrite the url.  It makes `localhost/16` the same as `localhost/profile.php?p=16`.  This works.  However, when i go to `localhost/16` the URL reverts to `localhost/profile.php?=16`. I would like it to say as `localhost/16` while the user is on the page.  How can i do this?

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/profile.php?p=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the full URL - that implies [R] (redirect)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?p=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```